# How to show that there is a unique unbiased estimator of $p$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

The taxis in a town are marked with reference numbers $1,2,...,p$ where $p$ is unknown. I am observing $n \leq p$ of them with pairwise different reference numbers $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$. It is to be assumed that every combination $(x_1,x_2,...,x_3)$ has the same probability to occure. Let $g:=\max x_i$.
How can I show that there is a unique function $f(g)$ being an unbiased estimator of $p$? Any hints?

Comment: Hint: find $E[g\mid p]$.  That should make finding an unbiased function of $g$ fairly obvious.  Uniqueness may be harder.  This is essentially the *[German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meat of this exercise is proving that g is a [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(statistics)) and [sufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) statistic. Once you have proven this, the rest is theory.

**Completeness:**
This is nicely worked out [here](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/41616-Discrete-uniform-distribution-completeness)

**Sufficientness:**
This is easy, for example using the [factorisation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher.E2.80.93Neyman_factorization_theorem)

**Existence:**
Take any unbiased estimator $S$ of $p$. This is not necessarily a function of $g$ yet, so let
$$f(g) = E_p[S|g]$$
Since $g$ is sufficient, $f(g)$ does not depend on $p$ so it is again an estimator.
By the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), $f(g)$ is again unbiased:
$$E_p[f(g)] = E_p[E_p[S|g]] = E_p[S] = p$$

**(a.s.) Uniqueness:**
This is where completness comes in. By the [theorem of Lehmann-Scheffé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem), any unbiased estimator $h(g)$ (that is a function of $g$) must be the [MVUE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-variance_unbiased_estimator). In particular, $f(g)$ is the MVUE. The MVUE is a.s. unique, so $f(g)$ is a.s. equal to any other unbiased estimator $h(g)$ (as it is also the MVUE)